# Multiply two columns of different dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiplication

I have two dataframes (both are datatype float). The first one is called `Prices` which contains only prices:

[image: df Prices]

The second one is called `Table_ScenarioPercentages` which contains percentages where the prices need to be multiplied by:

[image: df Table_ScenarioPercentages]

So what I want to do is multiply the value of Period 20240201 (Prices) by Month 0 (Table_ScenarioPercentages), the value of Period 20240301 (Prices) by Month 1 (Table_ScenarioPercentages), etc.

I've tried:

```py
Prices.iloc[:, 0]*Table_ScenarioPercentages.iloc[:, 0]
```

but this just gives a lot of NaN's and the wrong format:

[image: result multiplication]

Does someone know how to do this in Python?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I'm sorry, but this was the easiest way to show the data in my tables

Comment: Your motivation is clear, but when you ask for help, you'd have a better chance of receiving it if you format your question properly. The question and answer behind the link I've provided explained why images aren't good medium to share text information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Use `Prices['DATED BRENT']*Table_ScenarioPercentages['Supply Side Shock Up - Crude'].values`

---

As per the docs on [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) (italics mine):

> Operations between Series (+, -, /, *, **) align values based on their associated *index values*

Since the indices for both dfs (`20240201, 20240301, ...` and `0, 1, ...`) share *0* values, you end up with a new Series with the index values of both and `NaN` values as the result of `some value * NaN` or vice versa for each index value.

If you want to multiply on index *position*, use [`Series.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html) to get an ndarray (or use: [`Series.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.0rc1/api/generated/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html)). N.B. both Series need to have the same length in this case.

**Data sample**

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [20, 10]}, index=[1, 'A'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Col2': [10, 20]})

print(df1)

   Col1
1    20
A    10

print(df2)

   Col2
0    10
1    20
```

**Index-based multiplication** (cf. OP's *undesired* result)

```py
print(df1['Col1']*df2['Col2'])

0      NaN    # NaN * 10 (0 not in `df.index`)
1    400.0    # 20 * 20 (1 in both indices)
A      NaN    # 10 * NaN ('A' not in `df2.index`)
dtype: float64
```

**Multiplication by index position** (desired, with `Series.values`)

```py
print(df1['Col1']*df2['Col2'].values)

1    200    # 20 * 10
A    200    # 10 * 20
Name: Col1, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you ouroboros1! This solved my problem